# Posting to twitter from file

Tags: php, twitter

I have such php script to post to twitter from file:

```
    function win2utf($s)  {  
       for($i=0, $m=strlen($s); $i<$m; $i++) { 
               $c=ord($s[$i]); 
               if ($c<=127) {$t.=chr($c); continue; } 
               if ($c>=192 && $c<=207)    {$t.=chr(208).chr($c-48); continue; } 
               if ($c>=208 && $c<=239) {$t.=chr(208).chr($c-48); continue; } 
               if ($c>=240 && $c<=255) {$t.=chr(209).chr($c-112); continue; }

               if ($c==184) { $t.=chr(209).chr(209); continue; };
               if ($c==168) { $t.=chr(208).chr(129);  continue; };
        }
   return $t;
} 

require_once 'options.php';     
require_once 'twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php'; 
set_time_limit(0);  
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($options['CONSUMER_KEY'], $options['CONSUMER_SECRET'], $options['OAUTH_TOKEN'], $options['OAUTH_SECRET']); 
$connection->format = 'xml';
$lines = file(ROOT.'inc/posts.txt');
$index = mt_rand(0, count($lines)-1); 
$status  = win2utf($lines[$index]); 
$connection->post('statuses/update',   array('status'=>$status));
```

How should I improve this script to remove from file messages which I've posted already?

Comment: Please do not write your entire code in one line! Nobody wants to read or understand it like that. The common rule is: One statement per line.

Comment: Yes, but there is some bug with pasting on this site, it removes some text formating.

Comment: No, there is not. You simply need to paste your snippet as code instead of a quote (indent your code by four spaces. there is a button for that, too).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to move the already tweeted lines onto a different file.  Then one file will have all the tweeted lines and one file will have the lines that is yet to be tweeted.

Your function's readability isn't very great by the way.

Comment: I ask and I answer: $fname=ROOT.'inc/posts.txt';
$fdstr=$index;
$ftext=file($fname);
$fnew=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($ftext);$i++)
{if($i!=$fdstr) {$fnew[]=$ftext[$i];}
else {}}
$fdes=fopen($fname,"w");
for($i=0;$i<count($fnew);$i++)
{fputs($fdes,$fnew[$i]);}
fclose($fdes);